# Applozic Platform Chat API - Uploading message attachments

Tags: applozic

I'm integrating with applozic for a client, and I need to send messages with attachments to users. I'm following the steps here: https://docs.applozic.com/docs/1-1-user-chat-and-group-chat-api#section-send-message-with-attachment on how to do this.

I'm having trouble with step 2:

> Step 2. Call Url  With multipart :
>
> Call API with your file object  attached to files[] array:

the requests I send are rejected with a 405 error, for example....

**Request:**

```
POST /_ah/upload/AMmfu6ZQrGP3Szfk1GuQAb_2a3J7PPWhQoiRbTnEjLp2MIzpuoeHrYryXhlzI6NW9JikjpJbT-HEtHAIk3og-Gl5EesCzBASipgtq1Hvh-PN90sjvasjRBvtO5XIFWi08gGfqTYUNT0C/ALBNUaYAAAAAWocIx4JPtA2a7LU00w1_pRui2Q3NjLR5/
application-key: XXXX
authorization: Basic XXXXX
cache-control: no-cache
accept: */*
host: applozic.appspot.com
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------523557777486909202804628
content-length: 286288

--------------------------523557777486909202804628
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="attachment.pptx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation

....file data....
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 405
status: 405
x-guploader-uploadid: AEnB2UpLhLC9VKz0ysfP-WcNTgGCFc_67dVEp_-ANZsLTvWfEOFgyMWKKvpehGa3I6E9Q_s8S7LQAcYFlTt-J8LwVqRosha6lNros6eECUP5JdJ_RsZMW9g
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
access-control-max-age: 3600
access-control-allow-headers: UserId-Enabled, Authorization, Application-Key, Source, Content-Type
allow: GET
x-cloud-trace-context: 728352eed99001ff946db65f68daf518;o=1
x-appengine-estimated-cpm-us-dollars: $0.000026
x-appengine-resource-usage: ms=93 cpu_ms=605
date: Fri, 16 Feb 2018 16:29:37 GMT
pragma: no-cache
expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate
content-length: 0
server: UploadServer
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
alt-svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"
```

Could someone tell me what i'm missing here? It's responding with `allow: GET` which doesn't make sense, am I failing auth somehow?

Is there any more documentation available on this feature?

Answer (score 1):

### Step 1. Get Url to Upload File

Call API:

https://applozic.appspot.com/rest/ws/aws/file/url?data=1478763491992

where data= currentTime in long

API Response String:

https://applozic.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6YAZpXFUYvC7wqIcW7msh8-YF1d7Tsh1UOTSCzpx2vinrcLQRtVfWbFHHXLFunUqsSLe1dYsDbsJxIO28cNcGrECf7LfFaNSycct-Sybd9KAZWk0yk7HybzxbBp4YQEDmMLi4Uf/ALBNUaYAAAAAWovz3TcYX24yam5K3embIkgQ6Q1pGIRf/

### Step 2. Call Url  With multipart :

Call API with your file object  attached to files[] array(Parameter:files[]):

https://applozic.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6YAZpXFUYvC7wqIcW7msh8-YF1d7Tsh1UOTSCzpx2vinrcLQRtVfWbFHHXLFunUqsSLe1dYsDbsJxIO28cNcGrECf7LfFaNSycct-Sybd9KAZWk0yk7HybzxbBp4YQEDmMLi4Uf/ALBNUaYAAAAAWovz3TcYX24yam5K3embIkgQ6Q1pGIRf/

### filetMeta  json Response:

{"fileMeta":{"blobKey":"AMIfv96n1wlMLpa3R_1i4nbFc4L1RLG81W5RovnPqMhVspzzJv5WBbnYgI4uwZkNjvzszNqsWwEQU6mrYoYsaoa2Vhi45p3P7bvQhAO1ciEL1K1yZJ2HB-goYPULYumC7LA8h33p_Ry
JBewFK8FogMDPR4_4zjClIg","contentType":"image/png","createdAtTime":"1478763491698","name":"applozic.png","size":"8694","thumbnailUrl":"https://lh3.googleusercontent
.com/EfnmKkzLtwBgYQq9UWc26oVqSZUiGukhXQgq7ns9a3G53ZAveFOszamvsqD-tbOfuirqERBO0QR60xFgYiGr=s120"}}

Answer (score 0):

Try this request :
Post request
Url:-
 https://applozic.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6ZB1z1BBDQMh_ztllvkde5mest9aFeqDHoSmCLzGH3vEtqQLKKOZG820ONgNCOc3BatKJL-59Tppm76zvyfw773R4lEa7m3gaM4cdKGbDU5oy8R_9zt_PT12j8xYSK2oh3rO3xa/ALBNUaYAAAAAWoq31zwU986GLyomPgxjoJb6qHuf4iIx/

Param:files[]

Comment: Apologies the upload url has expired before I've had chance to test.